# круглый imageView

Tags: android

Как сделать круглым imageView ?

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView). Также некоторые image loader могут делать разные формы для картинок, например [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/rounded-corners-and-circles.html)

Comment: а как подключать эту CircleImageView библиотеку, подскажите пожалуйста, если не трудно

Comment: в build.gradle файле, который находится в модуле app, в раздел dependencies добавьте строчку compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

Comment: @MisterX Если вы потрудитесь прочитать справку к этой библиотеке, то там все написано - и как подключать и как использовать.

Answer (score -1):

Использовании CardView с угловым радиусом и ImageView внутри:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/roundedImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/image"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```